# Flutter Intl plugin – I am failing to set the location of l10n directory that is generated

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-intl

Hey I am building a flutter app and I am using the android studio flutter intl plugin, I want the generated files to be in src/shared/core/ but every time I generate them the go in the lib/ directory.

```
app/
- lib/
  - src/
    - features/
      - auth/
        - data/
        - domain/
        - presentation/
      - shared/
        - config/
        - core/
        - widgets/
```

Here is my l10n.yaml file, I tried following the documentation but it's not working and It is generating the files in lib.

```yaml
synthetic-package : false
arb-dir: lib/src/shared/core/l10n
output-dir: lib/src/shared/core/
template-arb-file: intl_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the fix didn't make that much sense but it worked.
First I run

```
flutter clean
```

then I moved the generated and l10n directories from lib (default) to core, I then changed the output-dir in l10.yaml and added generated to the end

```yaml
output-dir: lib/src/shared/core/generated
```

Then I made sure I have these in my pubspec.yaml

```yaml
flutter:
  generate: true
```

and

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
```

Then I commented everything with App localization and S and **run the app**, I then uncommented all the lines and reimported AppLocalization and S.